# Como importar Dump com 2 schemas para dataspaces diferentes

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle, oracle11g, dump

Tenho um *Dump* com do qual foi feito `expdp` com 2 schemas. 
Gostaria de fazer o `impdp` remapeando a `tablespace` para 2 novas
`tablespaces`.

Meu `parfile` atual:

```
userid=dba/dba@streetfight
dumpfile=expdp-ryueken-15072016.dmp
logfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.log
#sqlfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.sql
REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_RYU:RYU
REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_KEN:KEN
REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEMP:STREET
TRANSFORM=OID:n:type
```

Mas queria algo assim:

```
userid=dba/dba@streetfight
dumpfile=expdp-ryueken-15072016.dmp
logfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.log
#sqlfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.sql
REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_RYU:RYU
REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_KEN:KEN

REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEMP:RYU_TABLESPACE
REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEMP:KEN_TABLESPACE

TRANSFORM=OID:n:type
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como eu queria não é possível, mas para resolver o problema, devo fazer isso em `parfiles` separados, definindo qual `schema` quero importar, ou seja:

**`impdp-ryu.par`**

```
userid=dba/dba@streetfight
dumpfile=expdp-ryueken-15072016.dmp
logfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.log

REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_RYU:RYU
REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEMP:RYU_TABLESPACE

SCHEMA=SCHEMA_RYU

TRANSFORM=OID:n:type
```

**`impdp-ken.par`**

```
userid=dba/dba@streetfight
dumpfile=expdp-ryueken-15072016.dmp
logfile=impdp-ryueken-15072016_imp.log

REMAP_SCHEMA=SCHEMA_KEN:KEN
REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEMP:KEN_TABLESPACE

SCHEMA=SCHEMA_KEN

TRANSFORM=OID:n:type
```